I can't convert the uri to an image
I make a request to the server and get an object from which I take the name and images fields. Example of a request and response
http://94.228.112.46:8080/api/products/all

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abobaName",
        "images": [
            "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000004578"
        ],
        "description": "aboba",
        "count": 5,
        "winter": true,
        "summer": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "crocs",
        "images": [
            "content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FVK%2FHo35oAhlYrQ.jpg",
            "content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FVK%2FWDSOWvgMthI.jpg"
        ],
        "description": "crocs",
        "count": 1,
        "winter": true,
        "summer": true
    }
]

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DenisTopTop"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateProductActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DenisTopTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DenisTopTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Product.kt
data class Product(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val images: List<String>,
    val description: String,
    val count: Int,
    val winter: Boolean,
    val summer: Boolean
)

ProductService.kt
import com.example.denistoptop.data.Product
import com.example.denistoptop.dto.ProductDto
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface ProductService {
    @POST("products/create")
    fun createProduct(@Body productDto: RequestBody): Call<ProductDto>
    @GET("products/all")
    fun getAllProducts(): Call<List<Product>>
}

MainAdapter.kt

import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.denistoptop.R
import com.example.denistoptop.data.Product
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class MainAdapter(private val productList: List<Product>, private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = productList[position]
        holder.textView.text = product.name

        if (product.images.isNotEmpty()) {
            Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(product.images[0])).into(holder.imageView)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }
}

MainActivity.kt
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.denistoptop.adapter.MainAdapter
import com.example.denistoptop.data.Product
import com.example.denistoptop.service.ProductService
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mainAdapter: MainAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://94.228.112.46:8080/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(ProductService::class.java)

        // Выполните запрос
        val call = service.getAllProducts()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val productList = response.body()

                    // Инициализируйте адаптер и установите его в RecyclerView
                    productList?.let {
                        mainAdapter = MainAdapter(it, applicationContext)
                        recyclerView.adapter = mainAdapter
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }
}

I've tried adding and removing access
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Added getters and setters to the product
I tried to convert uri to png, but this is where the problem appears
As a result, the product name is displayed, but its picture is not

Are these images on the device? your server is returning a Uri to what would be a local device path for an image that already exists

Persisting content Uri values on a server is a technique that is very likely to fail. At best, those values will be valid for just one user, and even then you need to take steps to have long-term access to that content.

@tyczi, The images are located on the server in a folder, the request returns the path to these images. There are no such images on my mobile device

The request does not return a path but a content scheme in json notation. On what kind of device is your server running,?
